# How to stock and display in a list format a form's value

Tags: javascript, forms, list, addeventlistener, stock

I would like for each of the value entered in the form to be stocked and displayed in the list format `<li>`.

For example: if someone enters "Thomas" in the form it will display
. Thomas
Then, one enters "Sophia" so it displays:
.Thomas
.Sophia
etc...

What would be the best way to do it? Here is my HTML code.

```
<input id="prenom" type="text">
<input id="bouton" type="button" value="récuperer">
<p id="message"></p>
```

and the javascript

```
let prenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
let bouton = document.getElementById("bouton");
let message = document.getElementById("message");
function stocker(){
let valeur = prenom.value;
console.log(valeur);
 prenom.value = "";
  message.innerHTML += " "+valeur;
 }
bouton.addEventListener("click",stocker);
```

Comment: You mean stored - as in localStorage. To do what when? Also please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Ohh! you want them aligned vertically!?

Comment: Yes a vertical list:)

Comment: Try out the new answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work for me, try it.  Maybe you need to describe what you'd like to accomplish in more detail for me to understand :)

```js
let prenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
let bouton = document.getElementById("bouton");
let messageParent = document.getElementById("parent");
function stocker(){
let valeur = prenom.value;
  console.log(valeur);
  //prenom.value = "";
  //message.innerHTML += " "+valeur;
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = valeur;
  messageParent.append(p); 
}
bouton.addEventListener("click",stocker);
```

```html
<input id="prenom" type="text">
<input id="bouton" type="button" value="récuperer">
<div id="parent">
  <p id="message"></p>
<div>
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment

Comment: After the button press it does